# Suspect incomplete .pot file - what to do?

Tags: plugins, translation

I'm trying to translate the "Organize Series"-plugin. I have already translated all 166 sentences in the .pot file located in the lang folder of the plugin, however it looks incomplete.

- Many sentences stay untranslated in the admin section.
- The listed sentences are outdated, so I suspect the .pot-file belongs to an older version.
- Some translations are available, but don't get applied for some reason, like the one for `This entry is part %post_number% of %total_number_of_posts% in the series `

Which options do I have? Am I able to create my own .pot file for the plugin? I tried reaching out to the dev but I can't get into the WordPress forums (deafblind and CAPTCHA protection don't match, will have to wait for sighted help) and support by email is only available after purchasing a support ticket.

Anything I myself could do or will I have to reach out to the dev on the WordPress forum?

Comment: have you look at the original lang file ( if the plugin is english, the english file ). Does the have the same number of lines ?

Comment: The plugin does not appear to have an english language file - did not find anything in wp-content/languages/plugins, and there's only the .pot file in the lang folder in the plugin directory itself. The plugin itself is written in English and uses the __(), _x() and _e() functions.

Comment: @Gregory Checked again. There's really just the .pot file. If I go into the PHP source code I can see there are more and different strings being used. It really sounds like the .pot file is outdated.

Comment: so, add the missing string manually

Comment: Okay. Will try that. Although last time I tried doing that Poedit complained the file was broken after, although I explicitely used UTF8 in the text editor.